# Cart Throb: Shed light on CRON Job denial

Tags: cartthrob, subscriptions, cron

I'm working on setting up a CRON Job for Cart Throbs subscription package. At first I was getting a "Permission Denied" response until I granted shell access to the account, now the CRON Job returns with "403: Forbidden". What could I be missing?

I have "sh /copied/path/from/cartthrob" running every hour.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit too late to be helpful in your situation but in the event someone else runs into a similar scenario, here are a couple things you could try to resolve the 403 error:

- Restart apache if you havent done that since setting up the cron job
- Check to make sure the permissions on the directory or file the cron job uses are correct.
- Make sure apache has read/write access to the filesystem (its usually the www-data user)
- Check to make sure your apache conf or vhost have the allow directive set properly for the directory the cron task needs to interact with